# Prism WPF - View and ViewModel as Singelton - does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I am currently developing a WPF application and I am using the Prism Framework and the Unity Container. Everything works great so far. The Event Aggregator works fine, the Dependency Injection also and the navigation does so far what it should.

But I have a problem now, which I could not solve after a long research. I hope you can help me with the problem.

Problem Description:

1. The programm starts and the `MainWindow` displayed the `ViewA`.
2. Within `ViewA`, the partial `SharedContentView` is displayed.
3. I navigate to `ViewB`.
4. `ViewB` also displays partial view `SharedContentView`.
5. If I now navigate back to "ViewA", the partial view `SharedContentView` will still be displayed, but no content from `{Binding Items}` will be displayed anymore on `ViewA`.

Somehow the binding between View and ViewModel seems to resolve? :o

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

In the `App.xaml.cs`, i register the view as a singleton:

`containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<SharedContentView>();`
`containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<SharedContentViewModel>();`

The View / ViewModel should only be created once.

**Link to sample application:**

https://github.com/JackDaniel91/Prism.WPF.SharedView

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Click Button "Navigate to ViewA"
2. Click Button "Navigate to ViewB"
3. Click Button "Navigate to ViewA"
4. Issue: The items of the SharedContentView are on ViewA empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [post a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A screenshot of the UI at runtime clearly doesn't tell us what the XAML is like, and the XAML is important. Also, please post code and errors as text in your question, not as screenshots.

Comment: I am not sure but looks like `Views` you dont want to register with container you register the `ViewModel` with container. Register `Views` with `RegionManager`

Comment: are you sure this is a wpf question? this all looks very xamarin forms-like

Comment: WPF does not allow you to put the same UI element into the visual tree twice.

Comment: also, there's no need ever to have either view or view model singletons

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have added a link to an sample application.